# Difference between a constructor and an Object

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

I definitely need some light on this.

What's the diference between:

```
var MY_APP = function(){
    this.firstMethod = function(){
       //something
    };
    this.secondMethod = function(){
       //something
    };
};
```

and

```
var MY_APP = {
    firstKey: function(){
       //something
    },
    secondKey: function(){
       //something
    }
};
```

**besides the obvious fact that one is a Function and the other an Object**, what are the differences in code flow, prototypes, patterns... whatever, and when should we use the first or the second?

I'm so spaced out in this area that i'm not sure if i'm correctly explaining the doubt, but further info can be given if you ask.

Comment: The beauty of javascript is that there are no deep differences between the two. They are both based on closures, and if I remember correctly the second is just syntactic sugar for the first.

Comment: @num1 The two are very different. Object literals don't provide closures, only functions do. In addition, the properties of MY_APP will not be assigned until the function is called in the first example, but will be immediately in the second.

Comment: Additionally, the first example will **not** produce the same effect as the second. Running `My_APP()` will cause `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` to be assigned to `window` and become global properties, while `MY_APP.firstMethod` and `MY_APP.secondMethod` remain undefined.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, /me proceeds to go reread books on javascript.

Comment: @Box9 I had never realized that this.firstMethod would end up assigned to the `window`, got a little surprised on that one! Shouldn't `this` refer to the object itself in this case `MY_APP`?

Comment: @Couto It depends on how you call the function. If you simply call `MY_APP()` then no context is supplied and `this` will refer to `window`. However the intended use of constructors is to do: `var app1 = new MY_APP();` in which case the methods will be assigned to a new object, which then gets assigned to `app1`, but never `MY_APP`. You may also mix the methods in MY_APP into another object, e.g. `YOUR_APP = {a: 1};`, by doing: `MY_APP.call(YOUR_APP);`.

Comment: @Box9 don't you want to write a full answer with these comments? Pretty much because from my intentions that would be my chosen one for the best answer

Comment: @Couto I was still thinking about the best way to explain the differences concisely but figured the below answers covered the main points, although separately. But since you found it helpful, I will write a full answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key difference between the two is in how they are intended to be used. A constructor, as its name suggests, is designed to create and set up **multiple instances** of an object. An object literal on the other hand is **one-off**, like string and number literals, and used more often as configuration objects or global singletons (e.g. for namespacing).

There are a few subtleties about the first example to note:

1. When the code is executed, an anonymous function is created and assigned to MY_APP, but nothing else happens. `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` don't exist until MY_APP is explicitly called.
2. Depending on how MY_APP is called, the methods `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` will end up in different places:

   1. `MY_APP()`: Since no context is supplied, the `this` defaults to `window` and the methods will become global.
   2. `var app1 = new MY_APP()`: Due to the `new` keyword, a new object is created and becomes the default context. `this` refers to the new object, and the methods will get assigned to the new object, which subsequently gets assigned to `app1`. However, `MY_APP.firstMethod` remains undefined.
   3. `MY_APP.call(YOUR_APP)`: This calls my MY_APP but sets the context to be another object, `YOUR_APP`. The methods will get assigned to `YOUR_APP`, overriding any properties of `YOUR_APP` with the same names. This is a really flexible method that allows multiple inheritance or mixins in Javascript.

Constructors also allow another level of flexibility since functions provide closures, while object literals do not. If for example `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` rely on a common variable `password` that is private to the object (cannot be accessed outside the constructor), this can be achieved very simply by doing:

```
var MY_APP = function(){
    var password = "GFHSFG";

    this.firstMethod = function(){
       // Do something with password
       alert(password); // Woops!
    };
    this.secondMethod = function(){
       // Do something else with password
    };
};

MY_APP();

alert(password); // undefined
alert(MY_APP.password); // undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

The first is a function, the second is an object literal.  Since Functions in JS are first class objects, a function can have properties on it, just like any other object can.

Typically, if you want to create a "class" that you might be familiar with from classical inheritance languages, you would do something like

```
function MyClass() {...}
```

as is documented here http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

To answer the question posed in your edits, you would use them both in different situations.  Object literals are used to pass configurations around.  A typical usage pattern would be a method that accepts an object literal like so

```
 something.init({
      length: 10,
      height: 10,
      text: 'some text'
 });
```

and so on.

You could use something similar to your first example when creating a namespace.  Javascript has some interesting language features in that you can have so-called "self-invoking functions" that are of the form:

```
var myApp = (function(){
    var firstMethod = function() {...}
    ...
})();
```

the motivations behind doing something like this are detailed here
http://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/advanced-javascript/

You can also investigate the differences via your favorite javascript debugging console.  In firebug and chrome, I did the following:

> > > > var ol = {}; ol.prototype;
> > > >
> > > > var fn = function(){}; fn.prototype;

the first line prints undefined, the second returns a prototype with a constructor of 'function'

Comment: please don't state the obvious... i know that one is a function and the other is a object, still i can achieve the same effect with both. What are the deep differences between then, and when should i use one over the other, is what i want to know

Answer (score 2):

The constructor can be reused as is, the object literal would need to be repeated or wrapped in a function to be reused.

Example of wrapping the object literal in a function:

```
function MY_APP() {
  return {
    firstKey: function(){
       //something
    },
    secondKey: function(){
       //something
    }
  };
}
```

The object created using the constructor will have it's constructor property set to the constructor function. However, as you used an anonymous function assigned to a variable instead of a named function, the constructor will still be nameless.

Other than that, there isn't really any differences. Both create anonymous functions that are assigned to the properties of the object, so the resulting objects are the same. You can compare this to assigning named functions to the properties, or using prototype functions, both having the difference that each function only exists once instead of being created over and over for each object.

Comment: i think i got your point, but just to be sure, could you provide an example of how would the object literal needed to be wrapped in a function? if you don't mind? thanks =)

Comment: @Couto: I added an example above.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion in JavaScript regarding the difference between a function and an object.

**In the first case**,

```
  var MY_APP = function() { this.v = 7; ... }
```

or

```
  function MY_APP(x) { this.v = x; ... }
```

a function is declared, *not* an object. In MY_APP, `this` refers to the *global* object. 
Meaning that calling the function MY_APP(7) will assign `v` globally to the value of 7. (and in your case the function `firstMethod` would be declared globally).

```
  MY_APP(3);  // The global variable v is set to 3
  MY_APP(4);  // The global variable v is overwritten and set to 4
```

To use MY_APP as an object, it needs to be instantiated, for instance

```
  var obj1 = new MY_APP(3);
  var obj2 = new MY_APP(4);
```

will have `obj1.v` to be 3, and `obj2.v` to be 4.

Note you can also add methods using the `prototype` keyword (instead of this.firstMethod...)

```
  MY_APP.prototype.firstMethod = function () { ... }
```

**In the second case**

```
  var MY_APP = { ... };
```

an object, *one* object, is created and its name is MY_APP. The `this` keywords refers to that object, MY_APP.

Comment: Your understanding seems to be correct but your terminology is wrong: first, in the expression `new MY_APP(3)`, `MY_APP` is being used as a `constructor`, not an object. Secondly, `prototype` is not a keyword. Function objects have a `prototype` property.