# Why must we stringify arrays but not objects over requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, post, request

Last night I was sending some data to my server via AJAX (specifically, `$.post`), when I ran into the issue that JavaScript Arrays needed to be "stringified" and applied as a field to an object before being sent. That is:

```
$.post("/myUrl/", {"myKey": json.stringify(myArray)}, ... );
```

If I didn't perform the `stringify`, the format of the POST would get screwed up by the time it reached Django.

**Why do arrays need to be stringified for requests when objects can just be sent as is?** Or, does this vary wildly on the back-end being used?

Comment: The object doesn't get sent "as is". jQuery does some stuff to it to convert it to URL key/values: `http://this.url?myKey=stringifiedArray`. Objects are used because they're an easy data structure to manipulate.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So jQuery just doesn't do the same "stuff" to arrays -- or rather it treats them differently?

Comment: Ahhh..... That would explain why the `request.POST` was broken into `list[index]` bits; it is trying to create unique key/value pairs from the array! Is that right?

Comment: jQuery's post method accepts a data object (or string - see below) of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object doesn't get sent "as is". jQuery recodes the object to URL key/values pairs, for example:

```
http://this.url?myKey=stringifiedArray.
```

[The documentation has more information on this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

```
data
Type: PlainObject or String
A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
```

Objects are used because they're an easy data structure for developers to manipulate.

Comment: Hmmm... And an `Array` is an `Object`, but *not* a `PlainObject` is that the case? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048371/are-javascript-arrays-primitives-strings-objects)

Comment: The difference is an array is a list-like object that has numerical indexes and is sortable, and an object has key/value pairs wherein the keys must be unique and cannot be sorted.

Comment: BTW, the [MDN library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) is a great resource if you've never leafed through it.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the MDN library -- thanks. :) I was actually just skimming through it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It looks like the big difference is the *plain* object (`{}`) vs the more general object class that contains arrays -- and it seems jQuery only handles the prior case by default. Interesting! Thanks, @Andy!