# Javascript objects and method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, nan

Please help! i just started learning objects ecc.. i didn't want to go ahead, because i wanted to really understand the Objects on javascript. So i tried to write some codes of an objects with hourly pay,weekly hours,expenses,overtime and 3 functions.

```
var monthlyPay = {
//hours per week
     hourWeek: 40,
//pay per hours
     hourlyPay: 10,
//all the monthly expenses
     mothlyExpenses: 120,
//additional hours of work
     overtime: 7,

//function that calculates the bonus based on the overtime and hourlyPay plus 4
     calculateBonus: function(){
     this.Bonus = this.overtime * (this.hourlyPay + 4);
 },
//function that calculates the total monthly pay
     calculatePay: function(){
     this.Pay = this.hourWeek * this.hourlyPay + this.Bonus;
 },
//function that calcutes the remaining money
     calculateMoney: function(){
     this.Money = this.monthlyExpenses - this.Pay;
 },

};
monthlyPay.calculateMoney();
monthlyPay.calculateBonus();
monthlyPay.calculatePay();
console.log(monthlyPay);
```

It runs with no error, but when i look at the browser console the Money property has a value of NaN. Thanks in advance for answering!!

[image]

Comment: Well `Money` depends on the `Pay` value so you have to calculate that first.

Comment: The `this.Pay;` is not defined anywhere. So it would be `NaN`.

Comment: This reading could help a little : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441358/1636522.

Comment: You have a spelling mistake, you wrote mothlyExpenses instead of monthlyExpenses

Comment: Thanks to all of you!!! I really forgot about the orders that does matter when calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs in your code.
The first one is mentioned by Barden.
Pay is called before its declaration which is undefeined.
Also you mis-spell monthlyExpenses for your variable declaration.
Therefore: a calculation of two undefined value is also undefined.

Try to debug with printing values which may be used for Money:

```
calculateMoney: function(){
    console.log(`Params : \nmonthlyExpenses: ${this.monthlyExpenses} \nPay: ${this.Pay}`);
    this.Money = this.mothlyExpenses - this.Pay;
}
```

```
Result is :
Params : 
monthlyExpenses: undefined
Pay: undefined
```

To summarise: 
1. change the function call orders 
2. make monthlyExpenses or mothlyExpenses spell the same

:)

Answer (score -1):

summarizing what was said:

The order should be

```
monthlyPay.calculateBonus();
monthlyPay.calculatePay();
monthlyPay.calculateMoney();
console.log(monthlyPay);
```

And you should write

```
monthlyExpenses: 120,
```