# Put name in the position of a json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, local-storage

Follow the example of my json in storage object:
(sorry for the language)[image]

How can I put a name for the indexes "0:" and "1:" ?
Example: Replace "0" for "session_0"

Below I show in a more abstract example how I create this array in code

```
var objectFinal = {"student":[],"sessions":[]};
var mySession = {"answers":[]}
objectFinal.sessions.push(mySession);
var obj = JSON.stringify(objectFinal);
localStorage.setItem("",obj);
```

I hope it has been clear, sorry for my bad english or any desorganization.

Comment: If you give it a name, then it is not an array, it's an object of key-value pairs.

Comment: by the way, `mySession` is a javascript object, and `obj` is a string - there is no JSON array, as there is no such thing as a JSON array - unless of course you mean an array of JSON strings - which is nothing to do with the code you've presented

Comment: Arrays and objects are not really different : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441358/1636522.

Comment: @leaf Well, an array is an object, sure. That answer says "Except for the differences between them, they are not different at all!", which is somewhat tautologous.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You twist the reality a little bit, but I admit that this post might be hard to read for persnickety people that can't read between the lines. StackOverflow is not famous for its scientific papers right ? That being said, to clarify, with this post I just wanted to mitigate elclanrs statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `forEach(item, index)` function to build the desired structure.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var data = [{
    'datahora': '7758585',
    'nomeaplicador': 'Ele',
    'tempo': 000
  },
  {
    'datahora': '989887',
    'nomeaplicador': 'Enr',
    'tempo': 111
  }

];

data.forEach((e, index) => { 
    data[index] = { [`session_${index}`]: e };
});

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name the key using `[]`

```
var objectFinal = {"student":[],"sessions":[]};
var mySession = {"answers":[]}
objectFinal.sessions['session_0'] = mySession; // <- here
var obj = JSON.stringify(objectFinal);
localStorage.setItem("",obj);
```

Comment: This actually adds the property `session_0` to the `sessions` array object. It will not be an element in the array (`objectFinal.sessions.length === 0`).

Comment: That's right. To name the keys we need an object, not an array. As far as I know there's no way to name an array-key in javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an object to have custom keys. You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on `objectFinal.sessions`, starting with an empty object `{}`:

```js
var result = objectFinal.sessions.reduce(function(acc, current, i) {
    acc['session_' + i] = current;
    return acc;
}, {});
```