# How to keep elements with a given name tag inside an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to have an array that elements inside look like this:

```
Array(3)
0: name: true;
1: price : false;
2: stock: true;
length: 3
```

So when I need to get any element, I could get it by calling property name like:

```
if(array[name] == false)
{
 //do smth
}
```

How to achieve this using jquery?

Comment: Did `name: true` and similars are object?

Comment: you need an object for this kind of check.

Comment: `array[name]` seems like accessing an object property, unless `name` represents an index in the array...  in any case `array[index][name]` would be more realistic. A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you're trying to achieve and where you're struggling would be very welcome.

Comment: There's not jQuery required here. A POJS object has this behaviour out of the box.

Comment: 1) You need object from this not array. 2) This will be same for jquery too. You can't apply any jquery feature to shorten it.

Comment: Why would you want this "using jQuery"? jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: @lealceldeiro that would be long if I explain but this all stuff inside an array should refer to html input elements inside a form in order to make further validation check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will not help you with what you want to achieve.

You can affect the wanted property thanks to the following: `yourArray['yourProperty'] = 'yourValue';`.

```js
const arr = [];

arr['name'] = true;
arr['price'] = true;
arr['stock'] = false;

// Access properties like:
console.log(arr['name']);

if (arr['name'] === true) {
  console.log('name is true');
}
```

However,  be aware that the length of you array **will stay at 0**. So you will not be able to loop through it with a simple `for` statement neither a `for...of` statement.

---

**Note**: I suggest you to use objects instead, as arrays are not made to have string properties.

Please, **read [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048371/are-javascript-arrays-primitives-strings-objects/5048482#5048482) *@GalAbra* give us in the comments for further details**.

```js
const obj = {
  name: true,
  price: true,
  stock: false
};

// Access properties like:
console.log(obj.name);

if (obj.name === true) {
  console.log('name is true');
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in JS [arrays are objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048482/3103891)

Comment: so can I use obj in if else as a `if(obj.price == true){//do smth}` ?

Comment: @GalAbra - Oh yes, thanks for the link. I'll add it.