# Javascript filter but return keys rather than values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

This function works fine but I don't want it to return the values, but the keys:

```
const search = [2342,1900,1800,2310]

search = search.filter(function (el) { return el > 2200; });
```

So it should return `[0,3]` rather than `[2342,2310]`

Comment: *"So it should return [0,3]"*... why?

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado Because those are the keys....?

Comment: do you have the best data structure for your problem? maybe a type of map is better in your case?

Comment: @Hasen Ok, now I get it. That's what you *want*, the way you worded your question it seemed that you're telling us that `Array.prototype.filter` **should** return the indices... By the way, you rolled back a better title to your unclear title again.

Comment: @Hasen Arrays don't have keys, they have indexes

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado No, 'should' just refers to the expected output.

Comment: @slebetman technically speaking they do (there is even an `Array.prototype.keys` method), but I agree with you: *indices* is a better word choice here.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado Ironically the best answer is using `Object.keys`.

Comment: @slebetman I think it's slightly misleading to say that arrays don't have keys.  [Arrays are objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048482/5011469) in js after all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the keys, then use them to access the array, and filter based on that:

```js
const search = [2342,1900,1800,2310];

const result = Object.keys(search)
  .filter(key => search[key] > 2200)
  .map(key => Number(key))
  
console.dir(result)
```

Or, for something more interesting:

```js
const search = [2342,1900,1800,2310];

const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((v, f) => f(v), x);
const filter = f => a => a.filter(f);
const map = f => a => a.map(f);
const toPairs = o => Object.keys(o)
  .map(k => [k, o[k]]);  
const take = i => a => a[i];
const gte = a => b => b >= a;
const toNumber = x => Number(x);

const bigEnough = gte(2200);
const itemOneIsBigEnough = pipe(
  take(1),
  bigEnough
);
const getTheFirstItemAsANumber = pipe(take(0), toNumber);

const doTheThing = pipe(
  toPairs,
  filter(
    itemOneIsBigEnough
  ),
  map(getTheFirstItemAsANumber),
);


const result = doTheThing(search);
console.dir(result);
```

Comment: Yes this seems perfect although do you have any idea why it returns the keys as `["0", "3"]` rather than `[0,3]` ?

Comment: Oh yeah, like it with the `.map(key => Number(key))` to get it as numbers.

Comment: @Hasen Yes indeed I do; it's because `Object.keys` will give you an array of strings when used on an array; accessing an existing index of an array as a string (ie `array["0"]`) still works, though

Comment: OK I see. But in my case I need a bunch of ordinary numbers. Anyway, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to just [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the items:

```js
const search = [2342,1900,1800,2310]

const result = search.reduce(function (result, el, index) {
  if(el > 2200) {
    result.push(index);
  }
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get the keys and filter by value check.

```js
const
    search = [2342, 1900, 1800, 2310],
    indices = [...search.keys()].filter(i => search[i] > 2200);

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let search = [2342, 1900, 1800, 2310]

search = search.map((el, i) => {
  if (el > 2200) return i;
}).filter(el => el !== undefined);

console.log(search);
```