# What allows assigning array at index[some string] and underlying behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays

A strange behavior of array assignment at index: `array[<some string>]`.
Let's say I have a normal array:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3]; // undefined
```

If I type:

```
arr['.'] = 4; // 4
arr // (3) [1, 2, 3, .: 4]
arr.length // 3
for (a of arr) {
  console.log(a)
  // 1
  // 2
  // 3
}
```

Now I get some strange hybrid between an array and an object.
If I try to spread the array into another variable:

```
const barr = [...arr] // (3) [1, 2, 3]
```

Does anyone know what is going on and what rules create this kind of behavior?

Comment: Arrays are always objects. It just doesn’t usually make sense to put non-array-element properties on them. You can do the same with functions and dates, maps and sets, anything mutable.

Comment: @Ry- What does this mean "Arrays are always objects"? How does an array implement this assignment? Are there any docs?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048371/are-javascript-arrays-primitives-strings-objects

Comment: Everything is an object* in JavaScript. You can try to assign properties to any value. You can call methods on any value. etc. (* not actually everything, and this is an oversimplification)

Comment: @Ry- How is this a duplicate? `[...arr]` and `of` depend on the array's iterator; the length has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @AuxTaco: The main idea that the additional properties aren’t actually part of the array is the same.

Comment: @Ry- this is a duplicate of another question. Not the one you've mentioned, but the one CertainPerformance did. Read the question again.