# Looping through arrays inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

In JavaScript, it is possible to loop through an object using the `Object.keys` method.
With this, I can loop the `person` Object as:

```
  let person: {

    name:     "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age:       31,

  }

  for (let key of Object.keys(person)) {
     console.log(person[key])
  }
```

Now, how is it possible to do this if the `person` has arrays as properties?

```
 person: {

    name:     "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age:       31,    

    address: [{
     street:    "A Street Name",
     number:    190,
     apartment: 13
    }]

  }
```

Comment: paste real object. this can't be possible

Comment: You want to loop inside the `array` property?

Comment: [Javascript Arrays are also Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048371/are-javascript-arrays-primitives-strings-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Object.entries`:

```
Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        let keys = Object.keys(...v);
        console.log(keys)
    }
});
```

An example:

```js
let object = {
    array: [
        {
     prop1: 1,
     prop2: 2,
     prop3: 3
    }]
  }

Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        let keys = Object.keys(...v);
        console.log(keys)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what your're trying to accomplish, but going off your example, you can iterate `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` values:

```js
let object = {
  array: [{
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3
  }]
};

for (key in object.array[0])
  console.log(key, object.array[0][key]);
```