# Javascript get value based on dynamic key in object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I'm not able to get the value by dynamic key in following code,

```
const data = {
        "Id": "1234",
        "status": "open",
        "Translations": {
            "EN": "English",
            "ES": "Spanish",
            "FR": "French"
        }
    };
const translationKey = "FR";

console.log(data.Translations.translationKey)
```

How can I get "French" text from the object, If translationKey is dynamic ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation if you want to use a variable property name `data.Translations[translationKey]`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) you will find more details.

It's the same notation one uses for accessing array elements, since an [array is also an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048482/2721865).

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it can not be accessed like array..!

Comment: In javascript an `Array` is also an `Object`. Therefore its the same notation to access an `Array` property at a specific index.