# Typescript check multiple types ( react )

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have a type ImageType and incoming props from parent, it can be an Object or Array of Objects. I'm cheking if prop is Object then get directly access the "src" property but as you can see i'm getting an error from typescript. Any idea how to solve ? Thanks

```
type Props = {
  label?: string;
  value: ImageType[] | ImageType;
  multiple: boolean;
  cls?: string;
  getValue: (val: ImageType[]) => void;
  folderInCloud: string;
  [key: string]: any;
};

type ImageType = {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of images, please include your code.

Comment: Please post the definition of prev.value

Comment: all needed code in picture, the rest of code doesnt matter. Just Included component Props types.

Comment: @Shivam - posted. type Props is the type definition for prev and next.

Answer (score 0):

The reason TypeScript is returning that error is because it cannot narrow the type because [arrays are objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048371/are-javascript-arrays-primitives-strings-objects). You can modify the condition to use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) instead.

Comment: didn't help, the same ts error exists. 

 if (Array.isArray(prev.value) && Array.isArray(next.value)) ....

Comment: Are you not negating the check? An array does not, in fact, have a `src` property, so you would need `if (!Array.isArray(prev.value))`. Note the !. Unless you refactored the content within the if block.

Comment: @ftrsk is correct, you can just negate the `Array.isArray()` calls (probably both of them), depending on  how your `compareDeeper()` function is implemented.